# Ставится ли здесь запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, ссп

*Ясным осенним днём чистое небо синеет и сверкает в вышине(?) и летит, кружится и падает на землю золотая листва.*

Я думаю, что не нужна, т. к. "ясным осенним днём" - общий второстепенный член, но всё-таки сомневаюсь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы правы: запятая не нужна. Члены предложения, соединённые союзом ***и***, обособляются только в том случае, если являются однородными. А придаточные предложения, имеющие общее обстоятельство, запятыми также не обособляются.

Comment: А как же запятая между частями ССП? Если бы предложение начиналось со слов "Чистое небо...", то запятая точно ставилась бы.

Comment: Да. Я поэтому и написал, что здесь не ставится запятая согласно двум правилам: во-первых, о необособлении двух придаточных ССП, имеющих общий однородный член, а во-вторых, о непостановке запятой после союза "и", если он соединяет что угодно, кроме однородных членов (как бы ни хотелось поставить «интонационную» запятую). :)

Comment: Две поправки (раз нельзя редактировать комментарии):

Comment: 1) Не придаточных, конечно, а просто предложений, составляющих ССП; 2) Не после союза, а перед.

Answer (score 0):

> *Ясным осенним днём чистое небо синеет и сверкает в вышине(?) и летит, кружится и падает на землю золотая листва.*

Как вариант:

***Ясным осенним днём чистое небо синеет и сверкает в вышине... И летит, кружится и падает на землю золотая листва.***

Answer (score -1):

Можно и по-другому. Ясным осенним днем чистое небо сияет... И сверкает в вышине, и летит, кружится, и падает на землю золотая листва.

Comment: Можно, но не нужно. Вопрос сформулирован так, как сформулирован.